# Am I misapplying the chain rule when differentiating $x^{5x+7}$ with respect to $x$?

Tags: calculus, chain-rule

The problem I am attempting to solve is:

\begin{align}
y=x^{5x+7} \\
\text{Find $\frac{dy}{dx}$}
\end{align}

Here is my working so far:

$$\begin{align}
\text{let }u &= 5x+7 \\
\frac{dy}{dx}&=\frac{dy}{du} \cdot \frac{du}{dx} \\
\frac{dy}{du}&=ux^{u-1}=(5x+7)x^{5x+6} \\
\frac{du}{dx}&=5 \\
\therefore \frac{dy}{dx}&=(25x+35)x^{5x+6}
\end{align}$$

(Additionally, I'm having trouble using the align environment in Mathjax. This question wasn't formatted very well. If someone could give me some help in the comments, then I would be very thankful.)

Comment: In your substitution, you forgot that you need to convert the bottom to $u$ as well.

Comment: @razivo Thank you for responding so quickly. I'm not sure I understand your comment. Could you please clarify?

Comment: x is a function of u , so you can't write $x^{u-1}$ in the substitution step , you have to convert everything into one variable.

Comment: To compute dy/du you need to express y as a function of just u and not in terms of both u and x

Comment: With $u=5x+7$, you would have$$f(x)=x^{5x+7}\iff g(u)=\left(\frac{u-7}5\right)^u$$Also, I took the liberty of editing your `align` environment to get the equations aligned on the $=$ sign, in case you find that helpful.

Comment: @user170231 Thank you very much! I hope that my 'align skills' will be better next time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $u= 5x+7$ and $y = x^{5x+7} = x^u$ then if you attempt to solve $\frac {dy}{dx}=\frac{dy}{du}\frac {du}{dx}$ then you must solve $\frac {dy}{du} = \frac {dx^u}{du}$ but $x$ is dependent on $u$ so you'd have to solve $\frac {dx^u}{du} = \frac {dx^u}{dx}\frac {dx}{du}$ but to solve $\frac {dx}{du}$ we have $x$ is dependant on $u$ and .... and we'd have an infinite loop.

(By the way, if we treat $x$ as constant we'd have $\frac {dx^u}{du}=\ln(x)x^u$; not $\frac {dx^u}{dx} = ux^{u-1}$ which is what we'd have if we treated $u$ as a constant and differentiating in respect to $x$.)

To do the properly we need to express $y =x^{5x+7}$ *entirely* in terms of $u$

So if $u = 5x +7$ then $x = \frac {u-7}5$ and so $y =x^{5x+7} = x^u = (\frac {u-1}5)^u$ which  ..... just doesn't help.

Better we do: let $y = x^{5x + 7} = e^{\ln x(5x+7)}$ the let $u = \ln x(5x+7)$ so $y=e^u$ and we can do

$\frac {dy}{dx} =  \frac {dy}{du}\frac {du}{dx}$.

$\frac {dy}{du}=\frac{de^u}{d^u} = e^u= y$ was easy enough.  And we can use the product rule to figure $\frac {du}{dx}$.

Let $w= \ln x$ and $v = 5x+7$ then $\frac {du}{dx} =\frac {dv\cdot w}{dx} = \frac{dv}{dx} w + \frac {dw}{dx}v$.

And $\frac {dv}{dx} = \frac {d(5x+7)}{dx}= 5$ and $\frac {dw}{dx}= \frac {d\ln x}{dx} = \frac 1x$ so

$\frac {du}{dx} = (5\ln x + \frac 1x(5x + 7))=(5\ln x + 5 +\frac 7x)$ and do

$\frac {dy}{dx}=\frac {dy}{du}\frac {du}{dx} = \frac {dy}{du}(\frac {dv}{dx}w + \frac {dw}{dx}v) = e^u(5\ln x + 5 +\frac 7x)= e^{5x+7}(5\ln x + 5 + \frac 7x)$.

Comment: Thanks, this was a very nice answer as it explained why my method doesn't work before explaining how to do it properly. It seems that we are still using the chain rule, but only later on when we have rewritten the equation using $e$. Can this method be used in general? That is, in order to find the derivate of any function in the form $y=f(x)^{g(x)}$, we must rewrite the equation using $e$ and then use the chain rule? (I suppose some functions of $x$ are very nasty, so I probably mean when $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ are relatively simple (e.g. they are just polynomial functions)).

Comment: And, the essential problem with my method is that we are looking at a function with $x$ in two places. Rewriting $x$ in terms of $u$ doesn't help because we simply end up with $u$ in two places. On the other hand, your method means we can use the product rule as we are multiplying a function of $x$ by another function of $x$ (much easier than raising a function of $x$ to a function of $x$!).

Comment: @JoeLamond: One can of course write $f(x)^{g(x)}$ in the form $\exp\bigl(g(x)\>\log f(x)\bigr)$ and then use several times the chain rule, and also the product rule.

Comment: @Christian Blatter Thank you very much

Answer (score 2):

You forgot to put the x in the base of the exponent in terms of $u$.
$$x^{(5x+7)} = e^{\ln(x)(5x+7)}$$
Let $u=\ln(x)(5x+7)$
$$\frac{dy}{dx} = \frac{dy}{du} \frac{du}{dx} $$
$$\frac{dy}{du} = (e^u)’ = e^u$$
$$ \frac{du}{dx} = (\ln(x)(5x+7))’= \frac{5x+7}{x} + 5ln(x)$$
$$\frac{dy}{dx} = x^{(5x+7)}(5+\frac{7}{x}+ 5\ln(x))$$

Answer (score 0):

It is $$\ln(y)=(5x+7)\ln(x)$$ so $$\frac{y'}{y}=5\ln(x)+\frac{5x+7}{x}$$

Answer (score 0):

In your function $f(x):=x^{5x+7}$ a two-variables function is hidden, namely $$P(u,v):= u^v\ .$$ Therefore we have the total situation
$$f(x):=P\bigl(u(x), v(x)\bigr),\qquad u(x):=x,\quad v(x):=5x+7\ .$$
The chain rule then says that
$$\eqalign{f'(x)&=P_u\bigl(u(x), v(x)\bigr)\cdot u'(x)+P_v\bigl(u(x), v(x)\bigr)\cdot v'(x)\cr
&=v\, u^{v-1}\cdot1+u^v\,\log u\cdot 5\cr
&=(5x+7)x^{5x+6}+5x^{5x+7}\log x\ .\cr}$$
(Note that the product rule for $ {d\over dx}\bigl(f(x)\cdot g(x)\bigr)$ also comes from a hidden two-variables function, namely $M(u,v):=u\cdot v$.)

Comment: Thanks for this answer. Can I ask what the subscript in $P_u(u(x),v(x))$ means?

Comment: @JoeLamond It means partial derivative taken wrt to the variable $u$

Comment: @Aryadeva Oh, that makes sense. Thanks

Comment: You're welcome. @JoeLamond

Answer (score 0):

$$y=x^{5x+7} \implies \ln y=(5x+7)\ln x$$

$$\frac{d}{dx}\ln y=\frac{d}{dx}(5x+7)\ln x$$
Using product rule for differentiation,
$$\frac1y\frac{dy}{dx}=(5x+7)\frac{d}{dx}\ln x+\ln x\frac{d}{dx}(5x+7)$$
$$\frac1y\frac{dy}{dx}=\frac{5x+7}{x}+\ln x(5)$$
$$\frac{dy}{dx}=\frac yx(5x+5x\ln x+7)$$
$$\color{blue}{\frac{dy}{dx}=x^{5x+6}(5x+5x\ln x+7)}$$

Comment: You should replace $\ln(ex)$ with $\ln(ex) = \ln (e) + \ln x) = 1 + \ln x$

Comment: @fleablood: Unfortunately, I didn't get you. $ln(x)+1$ is written as $\ln(ex)$ so what's wrong with this?

Comment: It doesn't look finished.  It's not simplified and its redundant.  It's like having a $\frac 77$ in your final result and not bothering to reduce it to $1$.  Especially when multiplied by $5x$ we have $5x\ln(ex) = 5x(1 + \ln x) = 5x + 5x \ln x$ it looks very misleading and not done to leave it at $5x\ln(ex)$.

Comment: @fleablood. Oh! Yes, I got your point. Thanks